# PHP function inside a class function include

Tags: php, class, function

I am working with lemonade-php. My code is at https://github.com/sofadesign/limonade.

The issue I am having is when I try to run

```
class syscore {

    public function hello(){
        set('post_url',  params(0));
        include("./templates/{$this->temp}/fullwidth.tpl"); 
        return render('fullwidth');

    }

}
```

which then loads the fullwidth.tpl and runs function fullwidth

fullwidth.tpl

```
<?php

global $post;
function fullwidth($vars){ 
    extract($vars);
    $post = h($post_url);

}

    print_r($this->post($post));    

?>
```

it seems to pass the `$post_url` but I can not pass it again to the `print_r($this->post($post));`

However when I try to run `print_r($this->post($post))` inside the fullwidth function it says it can not find the `post()` function

I have tried a number of things like below

```
function fullwidth($vars){ 
        extract($vars);
        $post = h($post_url);
    print_r(post($post));
}
```

I tried re connecting to the syscore by

```
$redi = new syscore();
$redi->connection() <-- this works
$redi->post($post) <-- this does not
```

Here is my full class syscore

```
class syscore {

    // connect
    public function connect($siteDBUserName,$siteDBPass,$siteDBURL,$siteDBPort, $siteDB,$siteTemp){
        for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
         $m = new Mongo("mongodb://{$siteDBUserName}:{$siteDBPass}@{$siteDBURL}:{$siteDBPort}", array("persist" => "x", "db"=>$siteDB));
        }

        // select a database
       $this->db = $m->$siteDB;
       $this->temp = $siteTemp;
    }

    public function hello(){
        set('post_url',  params(0));
        include("./templates/{$this->temp}/fullwidth.tpl"); 
        return render('fullwidth');

    }

    public function menu($data)
    {

        $this->data = $data;
        $collection = $this->db->redi_link;
        // find everything in the collection
        //print $PASSWORD;
        $cursor = $collection->find(array("link_active"=> "1"));

        if ($cursor->count() > 0)
        {
            $fetchmenu = array();
            // iterate through the results
            while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
                $fetchmenu[] = ($cursor->getNext());
            }
            return $fetchmenu;
        }
        else
        {
            var_dump($this->db->lastError());
        }
    }

    public function post($data)
    {

        $this->data = $data;
        $collection = $this->db->redi_posts;
        // find everything in the collection
        //print $PASSWORD;
        $cursor = $collection->find(array("post_link"=> $data));

        if ($cursor->count() > 0)
        {
            $posts = array();
            // iterate through the results
            while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
                $posts[] = ($cursor->getNext());
            }
            return $posts;
        }
        else
        {
            var_dump($this->db->lastError());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are having some issues understanding the execution path that PHP is taking when trying to render your template. Let's take a more in-depth look, shall we?

```
// We're going to call "syscore::hello" which will include a template and try to render it
public function hello(){
    set('post_url',  params(0));  // set locals for template
    include("./templates/{$this->temp}/fullwidth.tpl");  // include the template
    return render('fullwidth'); // Call fullwidth(array('post_url' => 'http://example.com/path'))
}
```

The trick to solving this one is to understand how PHP include works. When you call `include("./templates/{$this->temp}/fullwidth.tpl")` some of your code is executing in the scope of the syscore object, namely:

```
global $post;
```

and

```
print_r($this->post($post));
```

`fullwidth` is created in the global scope at this point, but has not yet been called. When `render` calls `fullwidth` you're no longer in the `syscore` scope, which is why you cannot put `$this->post($post)` inside without triggering an error.

Ok, so how do we solve it? Glad you asked.

1. We could probably refactor `syscore::post` to be a static method, but that would then require `syscore::db` to be static, and always return the SAME mongodb instance (singleton pattern).  You definitely do not want to be creating 1000 `Mongo` instances for each `syscore` instance.
2. We could just abuse the framework. A much poorer solution, but it will get the job done.

fullwidth.tpl

```
<?php

function fullwidth($vars){ 
    $post_url = ''; // put the variables you expect into the symbol table
    extract($vars, EXTR_IF_EXISTS); // set EXTR_IF_EXISTS so you control what is added.
    $syscore_inst = new syscore; 
    $post = h($post_url);
    print_r($syscore->post($post)); // I think a puppy just died.    
}
```

Look the second way is a complete hack, and writing code like that will probably mean you won't get promoted. But it should work.

But let's say you wanted to get promoted, you would make good, shiny code.

```
// Note: Capitalized class name
class Syscore {
protected static $_db;

public static function db () {
    if (! static::$_db) {
        static::$_db = new Mongo(...);
    }
    return static::$_db;
}

// @FIXME rename to something more useful like "find_posts_with_link"
public static post($url) {
    $collection = static::db()->redi_posts;
    // find everything in the collection
    $cursor = $collection->find(array("post_link"=> $url));

    // Changed to a try-catch, since we shouldn't presume an empty find is
    // an error.
    try {
        $posts = array();
        // iterate through the results
        while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
            $posts[] = ($cursor->getNext());
        }
        return $posts;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($this->db->lastError());
    }
}

}
```

Then in your fullwidth function, we don't have to do any of that stupid nonsense of treating an instance method like it were a static method.

```
function fullwidth($vars){ 
    $post_url = ''; // put the variables you expect into the symbol table
    extract($vars, EXTR_IF_EXISTS); // set EXTR_IF_EXISTS so you control what is added.
    $post = h($post_url);
    print_r(Syscore::post($post)); // static method. \O/ Rainbows and unicorns.   
}
```

Comment: you rock! am not sure why, but your answer was straight to the point and well written. It does what I need and helps me do simular things in the future. Thank you